# "Бесплатный осмотр врача". Как назвать такую ошибку?

Tags: лексика, реклама

Нашла рекламу с текстом "Бесплатный осмотр врача ортопеда". Понятно, что имеется в виду, что человека осмотрит врач, но написано так, будто осматривать будут не пациента, а самого врача. Правильно должно быть написано так: "осмотр у врача" или "врачебный осмотр"? Но как будет называться такая речевая ошибка? Лексическая недостаточность?

Answer (score 3):

**Бесплатный осмотр у врача-ортопеда.**

Это **грамматическая (синтаксическая)** ошибка – выбор неправильного падежа в сочетании (правильно: осмотр у врача, осмотр врачом).

*Осматривать врача, осмотр врача* –  действие относится к объекту (беспредложный Р.п.).

*Осмотр врачом* – действие относится к субъекту (Т.п.).

*Осмотр у врача* –  предложное управление Р.п., обстоятельственное определение (где, у кого).

В данном случае грамматическая ошибка стала причиной **семантической** (смысловой) ошибки.

https://studme.org/1589031521925/dokumentovedenie/sintaksicheskie_oshibki

**Врач-ортопед**

```
Вопрос № 295156
```

Правильно: врач-хирург, врач-терапевт, врач-стоматолог, врач-ортопед и т. д. (сочетания с приложением). Если же вторая часть (обозначение специализации врача) в свою очередь является сочетанием с приложением и содержит дефис, то перед ней употребляется тире: врач – стоматолог-ортопед, врач – акушер-гинеколог. Аналогично: женщина-врач, но женщина – врач-хирург.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Обеспечение **однозначности смысла** при употреблении Р.п.  для отглагольных существительных в большей степени характерно **для современного языка**, в 19 веке Р.п. мог соответствовать и другим падежам, например: служить музам – **служение муз** (Пушкин), обладать молодой душой – **обладание молодой души** (Лермонтов), сомневаться в любви – **сомнения любви**.

Answer (score 1):

"Осмотр врача". Я бы не стал столь категорично объявлять это ошибкой. В словаре Морковкина находим:

> "**осмотр**, обход, часы приёма, кабинет, заключение подпись, направление, репутация, ответственность, опыт чутьё, спокойствие, уверенность ••• **врача**".

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Прививка для взрослого против гепатита А стоит 50 долл. , против гепатита В ― 17 долл. каждая. Плюс **осмотр врача** 11 долл.
>
> С 8.30 утра до 12 дня они ждут результатов анализов, **осмотра врачей**, справок. [Дуня Смирнова. Кровь (1997) // «Столица», 1997.08.26]

Спорно? Неоднозначно? Согласен.

На мой взгляд, "осмотр врачом" и "осмотр у врача" предпочтительней.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка только здесь: *врача ортопеда*. Нужно: *врача-ортопеда*. Из "осматривать врача" следует ли, что "осмотр врача" означает то же самое? Фактически все так говорят и пишут. Потому что короче.

Есть и ещё один момент. Осмотр врача чем отличается от, скажем, концерта певца? Певец активно действует – и врач тоже активно действует. А в "осмотре у врача" активного действующего лица как будто бы и нет.

Comment: Осмотр врача отличается тем, что слово *осмотр* образовано от переходного глагола (осмотреть кого).

Comment: Это действительно так. Мы можем сказать концерт артиста и даже выступление артиста, потому что выступать - непереходный глагол,.  Нельзя "выступать артиста", поэтому нет конкуренции между двумя формами (Р.п. субъекта и Р.п. объекта), поэтому и нет семантической неоднозначности.

Comment: Я просто объясняю, почему язык вполне принял словосочетание "осмотр врача". В нем тоже [уже] нет семантической неоднозначности, ибо каждый понимает его как нужно.